# Returning ZipFile in Controller after reading bytes from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, c#-ziparchive

I'm trying to read files from my database (varbinary) and add them to a zip file so that users can download all files related to a specific user.

From what I can gather, I need to read the files from the database, create the zip file, read the files into memory and then write that to the file (doing it without this returned a blank zip file).

It will save the files to the zip, but unfortunately the files are all corrupted.

```
    public FileResult DownloadAllDocuments(int userId)
    {
        // File name
        string ZipFilename = DateTime.Now + "_Files.zip";

        // Get files from database
        List<DocumentVO> Documents = DocumentDAO.DownloadAllDocuments(userId);

        var zipFileMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zipFileMemoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Update, leaveOpen: true))
        {
            foreach (DocumentVO document in Documents)
            {
                var entry = archive.CreateEntry(document.fileName, CompressionLevel.Fastest);
                using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
                {
                    entryStream.Write(document.File, 0, document.File.Length);
                }
            }
        }

        zipFileMemoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        
        return File(zipFileMemoryStream, "application/octet-stream", ZipFilename);
    }
```

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using `System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive`? Looks like you need another `MemoryStream` and use `zip.Save(stream2);` then pass that to `FileStreamResult`

Comment: @Charlieface I wasn't aware it existed until now.  Thanks!  I tried it (updated my code above) but all the files are corrupted.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Looks correct, maybe use `ZipArchiveMode.Create`

Answer (score -1):

Please try these codes instead of return File line

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    zip.Save(ms);

    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + ZipFilename);
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.ContentType = "application/zip";

    Response.BinaryWrite(ms.ToArray());
}
```